# How can I edit a .docx file in Dropbox on my iPad?

Tags: ipad, text-editor, dropbox, ms-office

I have all my papers in a .docx on Dropbox and I'd like to be able to edit them on my iPad. How do I do this? All the free editors I've tried only support reading .docx files and they don't have formatting.

Comment: I keep hearing rumors that Word is coming the iPad.  But not yet...

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Possibly a suggestion moving forward, if you change those .docx files to .doc, there are many more programs out there that can edit the files, e.g., Pages.

If you prefer to stay with .docx, previously mentioned QuickOffice Pro HD is a great solution, [Documents to Go Premium](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/documents-to-go-premium-office/id317107309?mt=8) is another solution and [CloudOn](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/cloudon/id474025452?mt=8) also tries to emulate the Office interface. CloudOn is still pretty new and a bit buggy, but it's free and may help in a pinch. I found myself in the same situation with school and found that batch editing my .docx files to .doc was well worth it in the end. Hope this helps!

Comment: Cloudon is great! Though it is buggy (and looks like Windows 98) it's free and works well.

Answer (score 4):

I suggest [QuickOffice Pro HD](http://itunes.apple.com/us/app/id376212724?mt=8) for iPad. It will allow you to connect to Dropbox and edit any Microsoft Office file.

Comment: QuickOffice does not support Dropbox any longer.